# How to explicitly pass router params to React Component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Does anyone have an idea how to pass the react-router params object explicitly to a component?

I want to make something like this, because unit testing would be easier if I could pass the ApiClient from outside:

```
function FooComponent() {
  const apiClient = new ApiClient('http://foo.bar');
  return (
    <Bar apiClient={apiClient} param={?No idea how to pass the token param?} />
  );
}

<Router history={history}>    
  <Route path="/test" component={Test} />
    <IndexRoute component={TestIndex} />
    <Route path="/validate/:token" component={FooComponent} />
</Router>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your component is attached to the route ( i.e. set as the `component` prop of `Route` as in your provided code ), it  receives a prop `params` from `react-router` where you can get the route and query parameters.  In your case:

```
function FooComponent(props) {
  const apiClient = new ApiClient('http://foo.bar');
  return (
    <Bar apiClient={apiClient} param={props.params} />
  );
}
```

For official example, look at : https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/examples/query-params/app.js

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider something like this to pass down the router props and add some custom props to your component for example.
I don't know if it is documented somewhere in react-router documentation

```
<Route path="/campaign/overview" component={(routeProps) =>
    <MyCoolComponent
        myCustomApiKey="secret"
        {...routeProps}
    />
}/>
```

You can now access `this.props.params` and `this.props.myCustomApiKey` in MyCoolComponent